# Keyboard keys switch

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xev

A few months ago I switched right AlgGr key with Super_R. The reason for this was that I was using my Ubuntu laptop with an apple keyboard, and wanted the similar key placement as I was used to on a mac.

Now I use another keyboard and would like to switch these back. Only problem is that I've forgotten which file I edited to make this change. I remember using `xev` to find the key codes for the keys, and editing some file.

Do anyone know what file I might have edited? I use ubuntu 22.

**Edit:**
Output of commands:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options                                                               
['caps:swapescape', 'ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl']
```

These changes were set using Gnome Tweaks.

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard                                                                                               
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="no"
XKBVARIANT="winkeys"
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: You have a couple of swap options in your user settings, but none of those involves the AltGr key AFAICT. (Such options can be controlled via  Tweaks.) Maybe check the `~/.profile` file.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. `/usr/share/X11/xkb` if you have edited them directly, perhspas `../keycodes/evdev/` and/or `../symbols/xx`

Comment: Thanks, that was correct, i had edited the `evdev` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I had edited was `usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`.